# What are the bumps in the F-22 Raptor wing for?

Tags: wing, feature-identification, f-22

[image: F-22 Underside]

As you can see in the picture there are several bulges or bumps in the wing that are located in the aileron and flaps. Somebody told me these are to hide the linear actuator, pushrod, and control horn. However, if the bulge is connected to the wing and aileron how is it possible for it to be there? If the aileron is moving independent of the wing, how is the bulge connected to both at the same time?

Comment: Contrail storage canisters

Answer (score 29):

Yes they are fairings for the actuating mechanism for the control surface.  I can't speak directly to the F-22's details but, this kind of thing is done on lots of airplanes.  The F-22's control surface blister fairings are perhaps a bit more sophisticated and 100 times more expensive, but the concept isn't all that special.

The blister on the fixed structure will have an overlap with the blister on the moving element.  The blister on the moving element, like the aileron in the image below, will slip under the fixed part of the blister when it moves down, and there will be additional material forward of the joint that is exposed when the aileron moves up to maintain the contour.

In the somewhat grainy image, you can make out a dark line along the interface between aileron and wing that follows the profile of the blister (along with staining that could be discoloration from seeping hydraulic fluid).  There is likely a flexible seal strip to provide the smoothest possible transition but with enough compliance to accommodate the geometric changes in the surface contour, as the two halves of the bulge telescope with each other, and still keep the aerodynamic seal.

[image]

In profile it would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: I still dont understand. Could you please post a video?

Comment: What don’t you understand?  Please be specific about what is unclear to you.  Half the bulge is part of the wing, and half is part of the aileron.  They are formed to allow them to move independently as John depicted  in his excellent sketch.  Unless there is an F22 mech here who can go take one apart for some photos that’s probably about as good of an answer as you’re going to get here...

Comment: @MichaelHall Also, I'm guessing than F-22 mech taking this apart, making a video of how it works, and then posting said video on the Internet would likely face a court martial very quickly.

Comment: @LukeJustin The blisters are indeed aerodynamic fairings to cover the actuators for the trailing edge surfaces. The blisters consist of two pieces each, not one. The forward half of them is part of the wing, while the aft half of them is part of the movable surface. As the answer points out, you can see the seem line between these two pieces on each of the blisters in your photo.

Comment: @reirab so what you are saying is that each half is connected via some sort of hinge so it allows it to move?

Comment: @LukeJustin More or less, yes. The two halves can rotate relative to each other. The mechanisms that connect the movable surface to the wing and which control the deflection of the movable surface are inside the blister. The blister is just an aerodynamic housing around them.

Comment: Ok..btw the video i meat a video of the aielron moving so i could see how the blisters move and how the look when im motion...i could find any videos like that

Comment: @LukeJustin I added some annotations to my sketch to help.  The blister on the aileron will be shaped to allow the overall contour to be maintained as the blister moves on the aileron hinge arc of motion.  Basically an arc shaped telescoping effect.

Comment: @LukeJustin, what JohnK is describing can be thought about generically like this. Think about the overlapping segments of a medieval Knight's armor. In order for the arm, shoulder, torso and/or legs to have movement and still provide protections, the armor segments are designed to overlap and move over one another to the extent of the design allows. A snakes scales would be another example of this idea in a nature.

Comment: @JustinA that's not bad.

Comment: @LukeJustin - your question is interesting, but , it's almost impossible you could find such a detailed video that literally shows the detailed workings of such a classified aircraft! It's just some sort of hinge that cleverly maintains as small a gap as possible. You won't be able to get any more detailed info than that. Thanks for the cool question. Don't forget to tick an answer please.

Comment: Ok thanks. I just want to a video of like a preflight check where they move the aielrons. However in all those videos its a striahgt  on view so you can really see the aielrons moving. That all I wanted to see. I wanted to see how the blisters moved when the aielrons moved. A detailed dirgam would help but I really need to see a visual irl

Comment: @reriab this is what i meant above

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSWgXz994XE shows the rudder move, with a view of a similar fairing.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, it is a ball and socket.
Practically, it is a cross-section of a ball and socket joint. It does not have a hinge.
The defined shape of the bulge is not set by its own motion at all and is shaped in the way that it is so that it will maintain its general shape at all possible positions along its plane of motion. I would assume the value is to the aerodynamic calculations and not having to constantly account for drastically different surface area and shape depending on if the plane if flying up or down;keeping values as static as possible. The drawing is pretty accurate in the way it shows what you are talking about, is essentially, a hinge 'cover'.